# Youtube Chromeless Player error codes

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Anyone working with the youtube chromeless player has probably experienced some lack of documentation on some subjects. In this case : ERROR CODES

All they give us are:

```
//2 – The request contains an invalid parameter value. For example, this error occurs if you specify a video ID that does not have 11 characters, or if the video ID contains invalid characters, such as exclamation points or asterisks.
//100 – The video requested was not found. This error occurs when a video has been removed (for any reason) or has been marked as private.
//101 – The owner of the requested video does not allow it to be played in embedded players.
//150 – This error is the same as 101. It's just a 101 error in disguise!
```

And basically all I've been getting are 150 errors.. which tells me very little about the problem.. (yes because the reasons for 150 are nothing like 101 errors.. odd..)

So far, from some dedicated googling and experimentation I have discovered that the 150 error may mean that the video may be preceded by a commercial among other things I'm not so sure of..

I would love to know for example: what's the error code for not being able to play video in current country (for countries like Germany)

If someone has more information about youtube Chromeless Player error codes please fill us in!!

Answer (score 3):

Actually, 150 IS 101 in disguise.... in a way... the old chromeless players did not support monetization which is ALMOST the same as "The owner of the requested video does not allow it to be played in embedded players." V3 of the player supposedly fixes this and allows those videos to be played.

My guess is that the error code for not being able to play video in current country would also be 150, unless it's 100 because not allowed might = private.
If you were really curious you could upload videos that fit certain categories and see what code you got back.